# How to sign flutter build IPA manually

Tags: ios, flutter, ipa, flutter-build, ios-app-signing

When I run the command

```
flutter build ipa --export-options-plist=<my_plist.plist>
```

Flutter still tries to sign the build automatically using the details specified in the xcode project, even though I have set signingStyle to manual, and specified a certificate and provisioning profile in the export options plist.

This results in a build error when trying to build in an azure pipeline, as the certificates specified in the project files are not installed on the Mac agent.

Is it possible to specify manual signing when running

```
flutter build ipa
```

Comment: I am working on the same problem and running flutter with the --verbose option to see how it runs xcodebuild.

Comment: Having the same issue. Did you make any progress yet?